# Use a generating series to prove that the number of partitions of $n$ in

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Use a generating series to prove that the number of partitions of n in which only the odd parts can be repeated is equal to the number of partitions of n in which no part can be repeated more that three times, for each $n \ge 0$.

Comment: This is a site for questions and answers. All I see here is an order. What is your question?

Comment: The "first" problem in this corner of partition theory is to prove that the number of partitions of $n$ with only odd parts is equal to the number of partitions with no repeated parts.  Have you seen the solution to this problem?